# Authorize.NET maximizing successful transactions

Tags: authorize.net

We are using Authorize.NET (AIM + CIM) to process credit cards. Recently I noticed that we are getting many declined payments in transaction log. Most of them are with status "decliner by issuer", which means we don't have any specific information about why transactions are declined. I know there can be various reasons for that, and in many cases the problem lies on customer's end, but my intention is to eliminate any problem on our side and make it work as smooth as possible. In addition, my attention is brought to the fact that some people told us that their banks treated our transactions as suspicious and declined them. I want to check whether we have any problem on our end. Here are the questions I have:

1. Were there any changes made recently in the banking systems that may cause more transactions to be declined? Are there any known changes in bank policies or technical stuff that affect transaction status (declined or authorized)?
2. When user purchases a product or signs up for our services, before processing a real payment, we submit $1 transaction to validate his credit card. Then if it is authorized successfully, we void it, save his data in CIM profile and process further payments (on recurring schedule until user unsubscribes from our services). The question is can it make problems by looking suspicious for banks? Is this an acceptable way of handling payments or we should avoid it for some reason?
3. Is there any documentation or article specifically on the subject of getting as much successful transactions as possible, minimizing declined transactions and eliminating risk of transactions looking suspicious to banks?
4. We integrated Authorize.NET into our systems about 4 years ago. The code runs normal, but is there anything that is outdated / changed / improved that should be caught up by our code in terms of getting as much successful transactions as possible?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a high chargeback rate? If that's the case, some issuers may have flagged you as a suspicious merchant.

A few others points that may have an influence:

- in which country are you based, and in which countries are your customers? Some banks tend to flag whole countries in their scoring algorithms.
- likewise, what's your activity?
- do you use 3D Secure (Verified by Visa and the like)?
- do you do all the address verification etc.?

Do you get the declines on the initial authorisation, or on subsequent ones?

Also, I suppose the $1 transaction is just an authorisation, right?

Have you tried to see if the declines come from specific issuers (recognisable from the first 4 to 6 digits)?

Comment: - I don't have a statistics about chargebacks. But what rate can be considered high?

Comment: - Merchant is based in USA, customers are all around the world.

Comment: - Activity is providing educational sevices in music area.

Comment: - We don't use 3d Secure

Comment: - We do the address verification (rejecting only if both street address and zip code don't match) + card code verification

Comment: - Declines happen on both the initial authorization and subsequent payments

Comment: - Yes, the $1 transaction is only authorization, once it is authorized, it is immediately voided and never charged.

Comment: - I don't know where I can look up information about issuer. I can only see LAST 4 figits from a customer's card, but NOT first 4 digits. Basically, the declined transactions happen for customers located in different countries, so I guess issuers are different.

Comment: A "high" chargeback rate is quite subjective, must the bar is usually placed somewhere around 0.5% to 1%. If you do recurring transactions and it is not easy for customer to find who the transaction is from and/or to cancel the subscription, you may get more chargebacks. Ensuring that what appears on the statement points them directly to your site, and they can cancel really easily is a must.

Comment: More and more issuers really like 3D Secure a lot. You may consider implementing it, but beware, it might affect your conversion rates. So it's a tradeoff between conversion and declines.

Comment: Also many banks just randomly flag transactions as suspicious (basically anything that happens over the Internet is suspicious for some). I know HSBC UK frequently denies transactions (even from merchants from which I have bought many, many times), and calls me to check if I was the one doing them. Then they reset it, and it all goes well for a while until it starts again. You need to be able to live with that :-(

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts on this subject, jcaron.